# Event Handler won't connect to Active Workbook for COM Addin

Tags: c#, excel, comaddin

I'm having trouble connecting my Workbook_SheetChange Event Handler to an active workbook. I've tried several methods to no avail, it just keeps saying my workbook or instance of Excel (xlApp) is null and throws the exception.

Here's the code:

```
private void createProject_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) 
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp;

        xlApp = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

        exwb = (Excel.Workbook)xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;

        MessageBox.Show(exwb.Name);
        EventDel_CellsChange = new Excel.WorkbookEvents_SheetChangeEventHandler(narrator.Workbook_SheetChange);
        xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SheetChange += EventDel_CellsChange;
    }
```

The problem is the last line and please note I've substituted xlApp.ActiveWorkbook for exwb multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Probably something went wrong in creating the Excel application. `Marshal.GetActiveObject` isn't the easiest way to create a `Excel.Application` instance. Try this instead:

```
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
```

Comment: I apologize for not clarifying, I want my code (event handler) to be activated and tied to the workbook_sheetchange event of the active workbook, once my ribbon button is clicked.  So in this case I'm trying to grab the active instance of excel and it's active workbook.

Comment: Why are you doing all that marshalling? Don't you use VSTO?

Comment: "it just keeps saying my workbook or instance of Excel (xlApp) is null " sounds like a problem with initialization though.

Comment: sorry I'm new to this, what would be my options with VSTO? are there better ways to get active instances of excel?  and yes it's definitely initialization because this works fine if I create a new instance, add a workbook, and add a sheet.

Comment: You own the instance when running VSTO. No need to marshal yourself. Really, it makes your life a lot easier.

Comment: so i create a project as a vsto add-in? and I shouldn't have to worry about this?

Comment: No. Creating instances of the application and so are done by vsto.